# How to access a controller in nested resources in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Once you define nesting of resources in routes.rb how do you access the actions of the child resource? e.g the following is not working:

```
form_for :comments , url=>{:controller=>"comments" , :action "create"}
```

whereas "comments" are nested within another "Posts" resource.

Comment: could you tell what king of css is that ? i never saw like that before ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also nest the resources in the form, like so:

f.e. create:

```
form_for [@post, Comment.new] do...
```

Comment: but since this still links the form submission to the "create" action in the "comment" controller... I'm unable to access the action without un-commenting the wildcard controller#action route in the routes.db

Answer (score 0):

If you have,

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

## You can then have following in the form

form_for(@comments, :url => post_comments_path(@document))